# A problem occurred configuring root project 'apple_sign_in'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, apple-sign-in

For the last 3 days I tried all I could think about- updated gradle but when
I run flutter build apk and flutter build appbundle and I get the same error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'apple_sign_in'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

In local.properties I have:
sdk.dir = /home/ds/Android/sdk

build.gradle (app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

  def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.danasugu.srcgo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: 'a76dd222-35a3-4391-98db-9fadfb653304',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0'
//    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.7'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }
```

build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Have anyone faced this problem?
Any suggestions, please? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've been trying to fix it the whole day! Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In android.gradle (project-level), try updating your dependencies to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
```

Comment: It didn't fix the problem in my case. Any other solutions, please?